PHP login logic with "resume previous login"
I'd like to realize a login mechanism in PHP, able to:

ask username and password the first time you log in;
don't ask again username and password if you re-access the site within x days since the last login.

Question: How can I realize that?
Schematically, I was planning to realize this login according to the following flow-chart:

The php function requestContentPage() is called. Then, the server checks if the user has logged in at most x days ago (box (1)). If the user did not access to the site at most x days ago (i.e. first login in a while, or first login ever), the login page is called through the renderLoginPage() function. On the other hand, if the last login has been done "recently", then (3) we retrieve the information of the user and then (4) we render the asked content page.

When the user in login page clicks on the button "log in", the function submitLoginPage($u, $p$) is called. Then (5), the system checks if user $u with password $p is the "users table" in the db. If so (6), the duration of the login it's set to x days, and content page is rendered (4). Otherwise, the login page is rendered again to ask correct credentials.
I'm quite sure I can realized this in PHP using "sessions" (i.e. session_start(), session_status() & co.). I've already asked a similar question

Calling session_start() several times

but I wasn't able to go further. There, you can find my PHP code attempt. There I'm stuck. (maybe some functions are named differently from the ones in this post).

In the other question you use session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => 86400]);. What's stopping you from creating a cookie that has a lifetime of a couple of days? Anyway, you could have clarified the other question, or included the code in this question. Now we're hanging between two questions.

You haven't asked a question. What's the issue?

@AlexHowansky I'm asking "How can I realize that?"

@KIKOSoftware I'm trying to restate the previous question, since it was very confusing... please, concentrate on this one

@KIKOSoftware if a session is already present on client and server, then calling session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => 86400]); will ends up extending the duration of the previously created cookie....... this is not what I want . I'd like that will pass x days between two password insertions

But that means a session can be invalidated while an user is visiting your website. Is that really what you want?

@KIKOSoftware on google, after a while, the password is asked again and no one complains about :D

Use session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => 86400]);. Why doesn't this do what you want? You never mentioned in the question why that is not what you are looking for.

"will ends up extending the duration of the previously created cookie" Citation needed. I have tested it locally myself and I can't reproduce this. Cookie lifetime is set only during cookie creation. Reopening the same session using existing cookie will NOT extend its lifetime

I've tried to call session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => 60]) twice within 60 seconds. The session duration has been extended!

How do you know?

@Dharman
``for ($i=0; $i<20; $i++) {
session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => 10]);
error_log("session_start called " . ($i+1) . " times");
if (isset($_SESSION["user"])) {
error_log("LOGIN - user is " . $_SESSION["user"] . " already logged in");
} else {
$_SESSION["user"] = "candyman";
error_log("LOGIN - " . $_SESSION["user"] . " is now logged in");
}
error_log("THE SESSION_ID IS = " . session_id());
error_log(print_r($_SESSION, true));
sleep(2);
}``

@Dharman on the first iteration, you will get "LOGIN - candyman is now logged in". In all other 19 iterations, the output is "LOGIN - user is candyman already logged in"... Additionally, session_id() returns the same id on each iteration.

@Dharman I expected a new id and a new "LOGIN - candyman is now logged in" on 5th/6th iteration (i.e. after 10 seconds)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


"don't ask again username and password if you re-access the site within x days since the last login."

Your problem here - or at least a problem - is that the access takes place using a cookie, and not only is this cookie set to expire within a relatively short time limit (depending on the server, and you might not have access to this configuration), but most servers have routines that might destroy the server side cookie data after a certain time, independent of your web site settings.
This is done, for example, by cPanel, a popular server management application. Notice where the documentation says that only the global lifetime value is used (not your website's), and if more than one value is detected (say, 8 hours and 20 days), the minimum value is taken into account.
The mechanism works like this:

the PHP code issues session_start()
a cookie is either generated or acquired from the client
a file with a name depending on that cookie is silently created on the server, or its existence checked; e.g. your cookie is 0xbaadf00d, the file will be /var/lib/php/tmp/session-baadf00d
if you sent a cookie and the file is not there, an empty session is created.
all your session data reside in that file.

Much the same thing (with Redis in lieu of the file system) happens if the session backend is e.g. Redis.
A shared server might do maintenance every 72 hours and allow users to set any cookie persistence they want... provided it is less than 72 hours. More than that, sessions will malfunction (some providers might even be unaware of this issue, having never encountered it before).
So in your scenario, after maybe one or two days the file is deleted, the client comes back with its old cookie, and lo and behold -- the server has forgot all about them. In this case PHP automatically starts a brand new, empty, session.
A possible workaround is to save yourself the session ID (from the cookie) in a database, and store a minimum amount of information there together with the session create or update time.
Then:

recover the session cookie ID (in the $_COOKIE array, using session_name() to identify the cookie you want). If the user is known, they'll reuse an existing cookie. PHP might blast the session because it no longer exists, but the received cookie will stay the same. It might get rewritten on the next call though.
use session_start() - this might change the session ID
check whether the sent cookie is present in the database and still fresh
possession of the cookie is enough for authentication, so be sure that the connection is secure.
profit (e.g. fake a successful login from the user the ID belonged to, and inject everything in session; also update the database with the new session_id, if it changed; you recover it with session_id() ).

Alternately, you can send a browser-specific token saved in LocalStorage, and inject the login data that way. This looks more promising because you can bypass the whole cookie thing altogether. Actually you can send the whole information packet from LocalStorage:

the "beforeLogin" page contains a Javascript that accesses LocalStorage and fetches a login object, or creates it empty - it redirects to the fullLogin page if LocalStorage is not initialized.
the object is sent to the server. Its mere presence is proof this is one of our users.
profit. The object is injected into the session, and the user is considered authenticated.

In this latter case you might want to save a security approval from the server - i.e., the server replies to a true login with a token like {$timestamp}:{$validation}, where validation = MD5("{$secret},{$timestamp}") - and the client will have to send this back on subsequent logins, when the token might get refreshed. This way, a client cannot "refresh" the token themselves, because they don't know the necessary $secret, and you avoid people logging in three years from now with a stale, and forged, package.
You will also need a "full logout" procedure that instructs the client to clear its LocalStorage.

I don't understand why would a web server delete the session file without the application asking for it. That sounds like a terrible web server that produces unreliable service.

All right, you are talking about the session garbage collection. Yes, that could be a problem with long running idle sessions, but that's not what OP was asking about. OP was asking how to have a session cookie last for a couple of days.

@Dharman I realize that. But the fact is that this might (and it actually happened to me) conflict with whatever garbage collection settings are on the server. Unfortunately, some providers believe in premature optimization :-(. The session cookie does last, but it no longer has a session associated to it.
